# The forward-backward algorithm

Tags: hidden-markov-models

I am following Chapter 9 in "Speech and Language Processing By Jurafsky and Martin and trying to implement the forward-backward algorithm.

As far as I understand, it does not estimate the transition probabilities from and to the start and terminal states. But the autors refer to a spreadsheet by Jason Eisner where those probabilites are in fact estimated.

In a tutorial paper by Rabiner, only the transition probability from the start state is estimated.

What is going on?

Comment: "In a tutorial paper by Rabiner" which paper?

Comment: "A tutorial on Hidden Markov Models and selected applications in speach recognition".

Comment: Equations 44a, 44b, and 44c are the solutions for the estimation of the probability mass function of the initial state, the transition matrix parameters, and the distribution parameters, respectively.